# How do I split this word using PHP?

Tags: php, php-5.3

There are many words like this.....

```
mathewthomas256
alexcannon5623
kohlanjame9568
nancycherikom257
```

how do I remove numbers from above names using PHP? there are around 200k names like this

Comment: Inconsistent question: do you need to **split** the string (explode() function or preg_match()) or to just remove numbers and leave the rest intact (function preg_replace)?

Comment: I think it is using preg_replace.

Comment: I agree, this is not a clear [mcve].  We don't know if this is a newline-delimited block of text or an array of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/\d+$/gm", "", input)
```

The regex is *"all digits (`\d+`) at the end of the line (`$`)"*. This works in a line-based manner because of the `m` modifier and globally over all lines because of the `g` modifier.

Answer (score 2):

```
$remove = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
$onlynames = str_replace($remove, "", "name here");
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace("/\d/", "", input)